# how to calculate |a-b| in matlab ?

Tags: matlab

I tried searching for available functions but did not come across any. Is it same as calculating Euclidean distance between two points?

Can |a-b| be calculated if a and b are matrices or vectors?

Thanks.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are vectors there are lots of ways to define such a norm. There is no single correct way to calculate `|a-b|`. What you need here depends on the context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = norm(v1 - v2)
```

The documentation is located here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html